# Error connecting to SAP using SAP NCo 3.0 host unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sap-dotnet-connector

I have an mvc application deployed on a server that trying to connect to SAP using SAP NCo 3.0 that giving me this error

```
LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode
ERROR hostname '123.50.52.01#' unknown
TIME Fri Aug 25 18:50:19 2017
RELEASE 720
COMPONENT NI (network interface)
VERSION 40
RC -2
MODULE ninti.c
LINE 895
DETAIL NiPGetHostByName: '123.50.52.01#' not found
SYSTEM CALL getaddrinfo
COUNTER 2
```

I already maintained the IP address on the host file.

Comment: are you sure there's no typo in the IP address? It does look like there's just a # sign in the address. If you're sure, could you post the relevant piece of code responsible for connecting to the SAP system? System number, client number and SID are maintained too?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add SAPgui to your desktop and connect first using the setting you have defined, this is a very basic error that says one of your settings or your SAP system is not accessible from your desktop. Once you have SAPgui connecting you have the right settings to use.

Later.....